# How to find out what the subnet is that is attacking me

Tags: ip, hids

I have a webserver and mailserver that I use for fun/learning/breaking. There is only one user who should be logging in; me.

I notice in the postfix logs and HIDS alerts I get a lot of SASL failures from a particular subnet (only last octet is different, eg 45.14.165.0) in a short space of time during an attack.

I am curious if there is a way to find out more about the "threat actor". Is it a botnet, or a company? The whois only shows the Web hosting company assigned to that block.

Comment: That's a little more complicated that it might appear. Some of your options require that you inspect the traffic from these IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way aside from maybe using `nmap` on the target IP which can be illegal in your jurisdiction.

Maybe a large company such as Microsoft or Google knows but they certainly don't make such things public.

Comment: I might look into that when I have some free time. I suppose I shouldn't be worried as the ones I know about are the ones getting blocked.